# Saving images from Django Quill Editor to Amazon S3?

Tags: django, quill

I'm working on a Django project and using the Quill Editor for rich text editing. I want to allow users to insert images into the editor and save them to an Amazon S3 bucket. I have successfully set up the integration with S3 for other file uploads, but I'm unsure how to handle the image upload specifically from the Quill Editor.

I am using Django Admin along with Django Quill Editor, specifically the QuillField(), in my project. I would like to store images uploaded through the Quill Editor directly in an Amazon S3 bucket. Can someone please guide me on how to configure and implement this functionality? I would appreciate any instructions or code examples related to configuring S3 and handling image uploads from the Quill Editor in Django Admin.

Comment: also interested for the solution saving filed in file or s3